# Why aren't the user inputs being put into the empty array?

Tags: javascript, object, addeventlistener

I'm trying to write a program so that once the user clicks the 'Add!' button, the string that they typed will be added to an initially empty array in an object, and then that updated array will be displayed back on the HTML page. However, when I checked what the value of the items array was when I typed something in, it still appeared to be null. I'm fairly certain that the addItem function is fine, is the problem in the updateList function?

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Homework 5</title>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">-->
    <script src="toDoList.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Homework 5: JS Objects & HTML DOM</h1>
    <div id="input">
        <input id="userInput" type="text" placeholder="Type a word">
        <button id="submit">Add</button>
    </div>

    <div id="output"></div>

    <h1>Design</h1>
    <h1>Challenges</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
var button = document.getElementById("submit");

var toDoList = {
    items: [],
    add: addItem,
    update: updateList
};

function addItem(string) {
    toDoList.items.push(string);
}

function updateList() {
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    output.innerHTML = toDoList.items;
}

function getInput() {
    var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    toDoList.add(input);
    toDoList.update();

    //clearing the text field for next use
    document.getElementById("userInput").innerHTML = "";
}

button.addEventListener('click', getInput());
```

Comment: put `<script src="toDoList.js"></script>` just before `</body>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument provided to `addEventListener` needs to be a function. If you put a function *invocation* there, that function is executed immediately, with its return value assigned as the handler. But if the return value isn't a function, the event listener doesn't work.

In your case, you just want `getInput` to be run when the button is clicked - `getInput` is not a higher-order function, so just pass the function itself, rather than invoking it:

```
button.addEventListener('click', getInput);
```

Like this

```js
var button = document.getElementById("submit");

var toDoList = {
  items: [],
  add: addItem,
  update: updateList
};

function addItem(string) {
  toDoList.items.push(string);
}

function updateList() {
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  output.innerHTML = toDoList.items;
}

function getInput() {
  var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  toDoList.add(input);
  toDoList.update();

  //clearing the text field for next use
  document.getElementById("userInput").innerHTML = "";
}

button.addEventListener('click', getInput);
```

```html
<h1>Homework 5: JS Objects & HTML DOM</h1>
<div id="input">
  <input id="userInput" type="text" placeholder="Type a word">
  <button id="submit">Add</button>
</div>

<div id="output"></div>

<h1>Design</h1>
<h1>Challenges</h1>
```

Comment: Hmm, it still seems to be null. I get this error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Run my code directly in SO: you'll see that it's working fine. You must be running your script before the document is populated. Either put the script tag at the bottom of the body, or put it in a separate file and give the script tag the `defer` attribute, or wrap the whole script in a DOMContentLoaded listener function.

Comment: I see what you mean, thank you so much! Out of curiosity, if I had to put the <script> in the head and have the items array initially empty, is the only option to add that defer attribute?

Comment: `defer` only works if your script is in a separate file - which it *should* be. But you can always wrap your script in a DOMContentLoaded listener function, no matter how the script is used in the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

You should not invoke or execute the function in `addEventListener`. Invoking function causes the function to execute immediately not when the event (`click`) happens. So remove parenthesis after the function name.

Change `button.addEventListener('click', getInput());`

To

`button.addEventListener('click', getInput);`

```js
var button = document.getElementById("submit");

var toDoList = {
    items: [],
    add: addItem,
    update: updateList
};

function addItem(string) {
    toDoList.items.push(string);
}

function updateList() {
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    output.innerHTML = toDoList.items;
}

function getInput() {
    var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    toDoList.add(input);
    toDoList.update();

    //clearing the text field for next use
    document.getElementById("userInput").innerHTML = "";
}

button.addEventListener('click', getInput);
```

```html
<h1>Homework 5: JS Objects & HTML DOM</h1>
    <div id="input">
        <input id="userInput" type="text" placeholder="Type a word">
        <button id="submit">Add</button>
    </div>

    <div id="output"></div>

    <h1>Design</h1>
    <h1>Challenges</h1>
```

Comment: Changed it but the items array still seems to be null, got this error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. The error message is for the .addEventListener line

Comment: @Karen repost the code you have, you can literally click the "run code snippet" button and see that it works.

Comment: Ah, I see it! Thank you! I guess it took the empty items array from the start, which was why it had that error :P

Answer (score 1):

I think, you have to loop through your array. to get the content:

```
    var x = ['apple','banana','orange'];
    var output = "";
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
       output += x[i];
    }
    alert(output);  //--> outputs applebananaorange
    alert(x.items); //--> undefined (whats your case)
```